# Unable to make CORS request in ExtJS 6

Tags: ajax, extjs, cors

So, I have my localhost with a page, which sends request to a remote site. I try to do it like so:

```
Ext.Ajax.cors = true;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "http://remoteaddress.com",            
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    cors: true,
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    success: function (result, request) {
        console.log("success!!!");
    }
});
```

So, I followed dozens of threads and set these parameters - `cors`, `useDefaultXhrHeader` etc, but to no avail.

However, if I build the same request in postman (request to the same remoteaddress.com), then it's ok.

So, what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: As I see, the whole problem is with `OPTIONS` method, but I'm not sure how can I switch to `GET` request. I thought, `cors: true` and `useDefaultXhrHeader: false` should do the trick, but they do not.

Comment: Remove `    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }` from your frontend code. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, not a request header. Trying to set it as request header is what’s triggering the browser to do that OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 1):

The request with the OPTIONS-method is a preflight request.

From [msdna](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request):

> A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the
>   CORS protocol is understood.
>
> It is an OPTIONS request, using three HTTP request headers:
>   Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the
>   Origin header.
>
> A preflight request is automatically issued by a browser, when needed.
>   In normal cases, front-end developers don't need to craft such
>   requests themselves.

The webserver has to answer it with the headers to allow the browser to do the actual request.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick fix for that

Open terminal and run this code

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_sess_1" --disable-web-security
```

Then just use that new chrome window for development and once you host your website somewhere it will not cause an issue anymore

***note this is MacOs chrome ***